# Exception in AVCaptureMovieFileOutput after setting a AVCaptureDeviceFormat on a video AVCaptureDevice greater than 1080p

Tags: ios, video-capture

I am seeing an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - no active/enabled connections.' ***

... when attempting to record video after setting the video input device (back facing camera) format to a higher-than-default resolution format.

My capture code is heavily modeled after the Apple “AVCamManual” sample iOS app, which uses AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to record video to a file.  I can paste some of the setup code from AVCamManual if needed, but I’ll start by just providing the code additions which allow the problem to manifest.  First, add a button, and set its target to nextButtonHandler.

Also add the following to the addObservers method:

```
- (void)addObservers
{
    ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(formatDidChange:) name:AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

New code:

```
- (void) nextButtonHandler
{
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat* activeFormat = _videoDevice.activeFormat;
    bool foundActive = false;

    for (AVCaptureDeviceFormat* vFormat in [_videoDevice formats])
    {
        if (foundActive)
        {
            // skip the full range formats
            if (CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(vFormat.formatDescription) == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)
            {
                [self setResolution:vFormat];
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (activeFormat == vFormat)
        {
            // flag that we found the active format, so the next valid one is the one we'll switch to
            foundActive = true;
        }
    }
}


- (void) setResolution:(AVCaptureDeviceFormat*)format
{
    NSLog(@"Changing to");
    [AAPLCameraViewController dumpCaptureDeviceFormat:format];

    dispatch_async(_sessionQueue, ^
    {
        NSError* error = nil;
        if ([_videoDevice lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            _videoDevice.activeFormat = format;
            [_videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not lock device for configuration: %@", error);
        }
    });
}


- (void) formatDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Changed to");
    [AAPLCameraViewController dumpCaptureDeviceFormat:_videoDevice.activeFormat];

    AVCaptureConnection* connection = [_movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSLog(@"connection: active=%@, enabled=%@", connection.active ? @"YES" : @"NO", connection.enabled ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}


+ (void) dumpCaptureDeviceFormat:(AVCaptureDeviceFormat*)format
{
#if DEBUG
    CMVideoDimensions dims = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(format.formatDescription);

    FourCharCode fourCC = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(format.formatDescription);
    unichar c[4];
    c[0] = (fourCC >> 24) & 0xFF;
    c[1] = (fourCC >> 16) & 0xFF;
    c[2] = (fourCC >> 8) & 0xFF;
    c[3] = (fourCC >> 0) & 0xFF;
    NSString* fourCCStr = [NSString stringWithCharacters:c length:4];

    NSLog(@"format: ........................................ (%d x %d) %@", dims.width, dims.height, fourCCStr);
    NSLog(@"    exposure range: %f - %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(format.minExposureDuration), CMTimeGetSeconds(format.maxExposureDuration));
    NSLog(@"    ISO range: %f - %f", format.minISO, format.maxISO);

    NSString* ratesStr = @"";
    NSArray* supportedFrameRateRanges = [format videoSupportedFrameRateRanges];
    int count = 0;
    for (AVFrameRateRange* range in supportedFrameRateRanges)
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            ratesStr = [ratesStr stringByAppendingString:@", "];
        }
        NSString* rate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f - %f", range.minFrameRate, range.maxFrameRate];
        ratesStr = [ratesStr stringByAppendingString:rate];
        count++;
    }
    NSLog(@"    supported frame rates: %@", ratesStr);
#endif
}
```

Once you’ve tapped the button, the device format will be changed.  You can continue to do this as necessary until you reach a format that is higher resolution than 1080p, for instance “2592 x 1936”.  Once you’re in that state, if you attempt to record video, you will see the exception thrown.

Note that I’ve added code to dump the movieFileOutput connection state after being notified that the format changed.  And when the resolution exceeds 1080p, the “active” state on connection goes to NO.

I can find zero documentation on this subject, and other SO questions/answers do not mention it, other than one topic which says that you should check the active state of the connection.

My main question is, WHY does this happen?  I’ve since learned that if I do not use AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, and instead use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, without specifying an audio input, the issue does not occur.  Is recording a video with audio not supported in capture resolutions greater than 1080p?  If that is the case, why doesn’t Apple say so in their documentation?

Comment: I would also be interested in any info on HOW to record hi-res (>1080p) video WITH audio, on iOS devices.  I know it's possible, because the FiLMiC Pro iOS app can do it on an iPhone 6s.  When I try using both AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureAudioDataOutput, the audio connection's active state becomes NO for any format >1080p.

Comment: Have you figured out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to specific device means you are getting crash on iPhone 4& 5 or maybe 6 family as resolution of video is different with devices.

You can change the resolution using the `sessionPreset` property. Default value of session preset is `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` which is suitable for high quality video and audio output.

> You can only set a preset if `canSetSessionPreset`: returns YES for
>   that preset. Availability
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

The possible values of session preset is:

> Video Input Presets
>
> Constants to define capture setting presets using the sessionPreset
>   property.
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540;
>
> NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720;

**AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080**

> Specifies capture settings suitable for 1080p quality (1920x1080
>   pixel) video output.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> Declared in AVCaptureSession.h.

Please refer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This does not answer the question.  I have tried: iPhone 5s, iPad Mini 4, iPhone 6s.  While these devices support some different formats... all exhibit this problem.  I want to know why this failure occurs, and more importantly, how can video recording WITH audio be achieved for resolutions greater than 1080p.

Comment: I cannot use session presets.  I need more control for doing things like setting a higher frame rate.  You cannot increase the frame rate without setting the 'activeFormat' property on the device.

Comment: @ToddOrler Have you found a way to record video without setting a preset?